# How to share proto files between client and server

Tags: .net-core, grpc

I have setup a Grpc service that contains two proto files (One with custom types and one for the service).

customtypes.proto

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package CustomTypes;

option csharp_namespace = "CustomTypes";

// Example: 12345.6789 -> { units = 12345, nanos = 678900000 }
message Decimal {

    // Whole units part of the amount
    int64 units = 1;

    // Nano units of the amount (10^-9)
    // Must be same sign as units
    sfixed32 nanos = 2;
}
```

greet.proto

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "Test";
import "Protos/customtypes.proto";

package greet;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  CustomTypes.Decimal value = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  CustomTypes.Decimal value = 1;
}
```

The server side project compiles fine, but when i add both proto files to the client project with `add connected service` (in visual studio), it generates the following in my .csproj file

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="..\Server\Protos\customtypes.proto" GrpcServices="Client">
    <Link>Protos\customtypes.proto</Link>
  </Protobuf>
  <Protobuf Include="..\Server\Protos\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Client">
    <Link>Protos\greet.proto</Link>
  </Protobuf>
</ItemGroup>
```

But when i try to compile it fails to find the the Decimal custom type.

```sh
1>------ Build started: Project: Client, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Protos/customtypes.proto : error : File not found.
1>../Server/Protos/greet.proto(4,1): error : Import "Protos/customtypes.proto" was not found or had errors.
1>../Server/Protos/greet.proto(16,3): error : "CustomTypes.Decimal" is not defined.
1>../Server/Protos/greet.proto(21,3): error : "CustomTypes.Decimal" is not defined.
1>Done building project "Client.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have setup a github project that contains everything that is needed https://github.com/AnderssonPeter/TestGRPC/tree/02779b47fda3128483698c628b4db05bc6b57c75

So how should i setup a project to share the proto files, the only solution i can think of is to create a common project and generate both client and server types, but it seems a bit wasteful to have the server types in the client project!

Comment: The protobuf files define the contract between your clients and servers. Each requires the protobuf files even if only to generate stubs in order to be able to interact with the other. It's incorrect to think of them as "server types" rather they're service, method and message types that permit the interaction. For this reason, protobuf sources (and perhaps even the protoc-generated files) do represent shared content and it may be appropriate for these to be a distinct, shared project.

Comment: I didnt add them as links by my self, visual studio did it? I could copy the files manually but that would force me to keep them in sync manually?

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio and so can't help with its behavior. Clients and servers share protoc-generated stubs and so, minimally, the generated sources must be shared. I use Golang primarily, I include the protobufs, clients and servers in a single repo. I *don't* check-in protoc-generated sources. It would be better to keep the protobufs in a separate repo. I use Rust and, when I want to generate Rust clients, it's inconvenient that my protobufs are mashed up with my Golang sources because the Rust client only needs to clone the protobufs to generate sources.